# Autodesk Forge; How to map OBJ to the meta / properties?

Tags: autodesk-model-derivative

I have downladed an OBJ file along with meta information and properties, based on an IFC that was uploaded to Autodesk Forge. Question is; How do I map objects in the OBJ to the correct entries in the 'meta' and 'properties'?

Comment: Not doable at the moment unfortunately: .obj format doesn't have any metadata attached to it so there is currently no way to establish a binding. We have logged a pending change request on the Model Derivatives in order to map the .obj group names to the objectIds in the viewer, which will allow you to achieve what you are asking.

Comment: OK that was bad news. Can you use an other format than OBJ to achieve this?

Comment: If you have an IFC as input your only export format at the moment is OBJ unfortunately, but as I mentioned our development team is working on it. I can't give you an estimate however.

Comment: I guess the next question is what kind of feature/workflow do you want to achieve? There might be alternative workflows but without a more precise idea of what you looking for it's hard to give further suggestions

Comment: I would like to upload an IFC file, and retrieve the model geometry and properties in a related fashion. I would like to render the geometry in WebGl (three.js), and when clicking an object, I would like to display the object's properties.

Comment: In that case I would recommend you use the Forge Viewer directly, otherwise you would need to reinvent the wheel, meaning you will have a lot of work loading geometry, mapping properties and implement all user interactions ...

Comment: Using the Forge viewer is not an option, as my 3D view has functionality that the Forge viewer does not currently.

If you could output the 'objectid' to the OBJ file instead of a simple incrementing index, this would be of great help to map geometry to its meta. Could this be an option?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned initially, we submitted a request to implement that feature. It is not yet available unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for helping, Philippe. Hope this feature will be available soon, it will be very valuable. Thanks :)